# Does using React with Meteor completely remove the need of having helpers in the framework?

Tags: meteor

I'm starting to get on the React train, but as I learn more about it, I realize that the way React components are constructed, it would completely remove the need to have helpers because both HTML and JS can be written in a component and rendered to the DOM.

But as I see it now, using Blaze with Meteor seems a lot more intuitive and the reactivity that is inherent with React can be easily replicated using Blaze + Meteor sessions (the way I build all my apps before). I see a lot of redundancy with having React when you can do the same with Meteor + Blaze and even easier at that.

Anyone who was experience with Meteor + React: Does it completely remove helpers from the equation? Is it a better experience using React as compared to Blaze?

Comment: Well you don't have helpers anymore, but you still sometimes need them but now you just use regular java script functions as helpers, and if needed you create a module file. It's more organized and it's the future, so it's definitely easier to play with blaze but the JS community is moving in a different direction, It's better not to get left out, In one sentence it's less easier but more powerful/organized/testable code.

Comment: There are two parts to your question, the factual question about React and helpers and the answer is *yes* - with React no more helpers. Helpers are a Blaze construct.

The second question about pros/cons of React vs. Blaze is opinion-oriented and thus better suited for the Meteor Forums.